# Specific day of current month and current year from date time SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Hello everyone i want search data from invoices and client by today date I'm using DateDiff() GETDATE() functions for example two tables

1 Client

```
 - ID   int
 - Name Varcher
```

2 Invoice

```
 - ID int
 - ClientID int
 - date  Datetime
 - Total  money
```

query

```
 Select * from client c 
 inner join invoice i on c.id = i.ClientID 
 WHERE DateDiff(dd, i.date, getdate()) = 0
```

I want select query by specific day of current month and current year from date time
if the current month is 08 and current year 2010 i want write any day of month
**Thanks every one help me**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to select records from a specific day in the current month and year is to declare a datetime variable assigned to the specified day, month and year, and replace `getdate()` in your query with the variable - like so:

```
declare @date datetime 

select @date = '10-Aug-2010'

Select * from client c 
inner join invoice i on c.id = i.ClientID 
WHERE DateDiff(dd, i.date, @date) = 0
```

EDIT: To run a query for a specified day of the month in the current month, try the following:

```
declare @day integer

select @day = 10

Select * from client c 
inner join invoice i on c.id = i.ClientID 
WHERE DateDiff(dd, i.date, dateadd(dd,@day-datepart(dd,getdate()),getdate())) = 0
```

Comment: i know that but current month and current year fixed if i run query after month must be change date it is not i want
when i run query the query get month and year from date time now
so i want write day only in the query thank you

Comment: thank you it is true
if you have any article about datetime, DateDiff(), Dateadd(), getdate() functions but don't send MSDN i read it i need more and examples.
Thanks for help me

Answer (score 3):

here is one way which will also be able to use an index

```
where i.date >= DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
and i.date < DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), 1)
```

Comment: I want select query by specific day of current month and current year from date time
if the current month is 08 and current year 2010
i want write any day of month

Comment: change getdate() to anydate, should work just fine so if you want tomorrow you do '20100823'