# Records from the last 2 years - complete months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got code to pull back data up to the last day of the last month but I want records from the past 2 years complete month i.e. March 2013 - March 2015 so I need code to limit from 1st March 2013

This is what I have so far

```
select * from table where Date <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you show some sample data and the result you're trying to get from it please?

Comment: It might help if you give us an understanding of what you table looks like. Does it simply have a Date field that you want to use as filter? or are there other ways of determining where an entry was from?

Comment: what is sqlserver version `select @@VERSION`

Comment: So yes the date field needs to be a filter so DATE >= 1st march 2013 and DATE <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)) I'm just struggling for the 1st March 2013 syntax

Comment: I'm sure I get what you are asking, you want to know how to define 1st March 2013 in sql so you can use it as a filter? If so this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543582/specific-day-of-current-month-and-current-year-from-date-time-sql-server-2005?rq=1

Comment: But obviously the 1st March can change - I need it to be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the current date passed in `@CurrentDate` , You can get the last date of the previous month and the date 2 year ago based on the sql below

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DECLARE @LastMonthEOMDate DATE
DECLARE @TwoYearOldDate DATE

SET @LastMonthEOMDate = DATEADD(DAY,-DATEPART(day,@CurrentDate),@CurrentDate)
SET @TwoYearOldDate = DATEADD(YEAR,-2,@LastMonthEOMDate)

SELECT @CurrentDate,@LastMonthEOMDate,@TwoYearOldDate


select * from table where Date >= @TwoYearOldDate AND Date <= @LastMonthEOMDate
```